# Как реализовать связь много ко многим в доп таблице?

Tags: php, doctrine

Мне нужно реализовать связь 3 таблиц и добавить в связующую таблицу колонку типа int.
Departments

```
<?php
namespace Models;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="department")
 */
class Departments
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   */
  private int $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true)
   */
  private string $title;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default":1})
   */
  private int $position = 1;

  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getTitle()
  {
    return $this->title;
  }

  public function getPosition()
  {
    return $this->position;
  }

  public function setTitle($title)
  {
    $this->title = $title;
  }

  public function setPosition($position)
  {
    $this->position = $position;
  }
}
```

Ranks

```
<?php
namespace Models;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ranks")
 */
class Ranks
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   */
  private int $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true)
   */
  private string $title;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default": 1})
   */
  private int $position = 1;

  public function getId(): int
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function setId(int $id): Ranks
  {
    $this->id = $id;
    return $this;
  }

  public function getTitle(): string
  {
    return $this->title;
  }

  public function setTitle(string $title): Ranks
  {
    $this->title = $title;
    return $this;
  }

  public function getPosition(): int
  {
    return $this->position;
  }

  public function setPosition(int $position): Ranks
  {
    $this->position = $position;
    return $this;
  }
}
```

People

```
<?php
namespace Models;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="people")
 */
class People
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   */
  private int $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="full_name", type="string", length="150")
   */
  private string $fullName;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="date")
   */
  private \DateTime $birthday;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
   */
  private string $address;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
   */
  private string $phone;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
   */
  private string $workPhone;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
   */
  private string $email;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
   */
  private string $img;

  public function getId(): int
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function setId(int $id): void
  {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function getFullName(): string
  {
    return $this->fullName;
  }

  public function setFullName(string $fullName): void
  {
    $this->fullName = $fullName;
  }

  public function getBirthday(): \DateTime
  {
    return $this->birthday;
  }

  public function setBirthday(\DateTime $birthday): void
  {
    $this->birthday = $birthday;
  }

  public function getAddress(): string
  {
    return $this->address;
  }

  public function setAddress(string $address): void
  {
    $this->address = $address;
  }

  public function getPhone(): string
  {
    return $this->phone;
  }

  public function setPhone(string $phone): void
  {
    $this->phone = $phone;
  }

  public function getWorkPhone(): string
  {
    return $this->workPhone;
  }

  public function setWorkPhone(string $workPhone): void
  {
    $this->workPhone = $workPhone;
  }

  public function getEmail(): string
  {
    return $this->email;
  }

  public function setEmail(string $email): void
  {
    $this->email = $email;
  }

  public function getImg(): string
  {
    return $this->img;
  }

  public function setImg(string $img): void
  {
    $this->img = $img;
  }
}
```

И связующая таблица

```
<?php
namespace Models;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="people_rank")
 */
class PeopleRanks
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   */
  private int $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Models\People")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="people_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private int $peopleId;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Models\Ranks")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rank_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private int $rankId;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Models\Departments")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="departments_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private int $departmentsId;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default": 1})
   */
  private int $position = 1;

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getId(): int
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $id
   */
  public function setId(int $id): void
  {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getPeopleId(): int
  {
    return $this->peopleId;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $peopleId
   */
  public function setPeopleId(int $peopleId): void
  {
    $this->peopleId = $peopleId;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getRankId(): int
  {
    return $this->rankId;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $rankId
   */
  public function setRankId(int $rankId): void
  {
    $this->rankId = $rankId;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getDepartmentsId(): int
  {
    return $this->departmentsId;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $departmentsId
   */
  public function setDepartmentsId(int $departmentsId): void
  {
    $this->departmentsId = $departmentsId;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getPosition(): int
  {
    return $this->position;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $position
   */
  public function setPosition(int $position): void
  {
    $this->position = $position;
  }
}
```

Вопрос следующий, как сделать так, что бы через People можно было получить все связанные данные? Или это можно только через таблицу PeopleRanks?
ManyToOne Пришлось использовать т.к не совсем понятно, как сделать таблицу через ManyToMany и при этом добавить в связующую position т.к она генерируется автоматически